# What does this code mean + Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nszombie

I am having a bit difficulty in understanding following code.

```
    #define ENABLE_MEMORY_DEBUG 0

#if ENABLE_MEMORY_DEBUG
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR

extern BOOL NSDebugEnabled;
extern BOOL NSZombieEnabled;
extern BOOL NSHangOnUncaughtException;
extern BOOL NSDeallocateZombies;

#endif
#endif

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if ENABLE_MEMORY_DEBUG
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    NSDebugEnabled = YES;
    NSZombieEnabled = YES;
    NSHangOnUncaughtException = YES;
    NSDeallocateZombies = NO;
#endif
#endif
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil,nil);
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

Is this a way to enable NSZombie programmtically? Are these any pre defined BOOL variables - NSDebugEnabled, NSZombieEnabled,  NSHangOnUncaughtException, NSDeallocateZombies??
I have never enabled NSZombie like this. I used to enable NSZombie from Edit Scheme->Environmental variables and then adding NSZombiewEnables variable with value TRUE.

Any ideas,

Thanx,
Regards,
Tek3

Comment: I would guess that those features are enabled (in this particular project) when the memory debug flag is set on the simulator.  The global values are just used to communicate to the rest of the code without the need for `#if` statements everywhere.

Comment: @HotLicks : I think the variables - NSDebugEnabled, NSZombieEnabled, NSHangOnUncaughtException, NSDeallocateZombies, are all predefined variables. I searched the whole project to find out if these BOOL variables are used else where but they are only used in main file. So i guess these are predefined variables.

Comment: Yes, they are predefined. You cleraly see this as their declaration uses the `extern`key word. And yes, this is a way of setting the values programmatically. I am just not quite sure about the prerequisites within the project, wether they need to be defined or set in any project internal plist file.

Comment: @HermannKlecker: Thanx a lot for the reply. But use of extern varible doesn't necessarily mean that the variables are pre defined. For example we use extern keyword whenever we need to declare our own custom Global variables in the project. Am I correct in this regard ?

Comment: @HermannKlecker I cannot a reference to those variables in Apple's docs, other than as environment variables.  Where are they defined?

Comment: Apologies. That is what I mean by saying that I donnot know the prerequisites out of the top of my head. It may well be that the variabes still need to be defined within a plist file, as usual, and that only their current value is set within the code.